# Which license does psycopg2 exactly use

Tags: license-compatibility, python

using psycopg2 of version 2.2.2

the LGPL as LICENSE file declares, or the item in module setup.py. even in this module, there are two different license:

- License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) on module level
- license="GPL with exceptions or ZPL" in setup function

Answer (score 1):

The [license pages](http://initd.org/psycopg/license/) states:

> psycopg2 and the LGPL
>
> psycopg2 is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
>   ...

And then:

> Alternative licenses
>
> If you prefer you can use the Zope Database Adapter ZPsycopgDA (i.e., every file inside the ZPsycopgDA directory) user the ZPL license as published on the Zope web site.
>   ...

It is your choice.

Comment: I checked the source of different version. before version 2.5.4, there are still some file using GPL. finally, I chose the "GPL with exceptions or ZPL" in setup function with version 2.2.2